# MCP2210 - Plug n' Play HID Keyboard

Tags: usb, spi, microchip, esp8266

I'm working on something at the moment that uses an ESP32. I would like to have simple strings that I can specify within the ESP32 code to automatically "type" on the screen. For example, if I did keyboardWrite("Hello World") and I had a blank notepad open on the PC/Mac, it would automatically write Hello World.

I realise the ESP32 does not have a USB interface, so I decided on using an MCP2210(SPI->USB bridge) to take information (simple strings) from the ESP32 via SPI and then transfer them to the PC. Microchip claims that it is a plug n' play device however they supply a .dll to develop applications for it.

My question is - is there any way to carry this out without having to develop/install any custom software or drivers or any .dll and it would simply be a plug n' play device for PC/Mac. For example, is there any way to embed the functionality of sending keyboard strokes from the MCP2210 itself, rather than through an application on the PC/Mac.

In short, how can I interface an ESP32 to USB to emulate a USB keyboard without any extra software.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. It's not clear what WiFi and BLE have to do with your question which, I think, can be summarised as, "How can I interface an ESP32 to USB to emulate a USB keyboard?".

Comment: My apologies. I'll clear this up now.

Comment: I know very little about this but suspected that some of the Arduinos can do this. Read Arduino.cc's [Keyboard](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/) page to get a flavour of the problems you might encounter. A quick search for USB keyboard emulation will give you a load to digest.

Comment: Do you *need* USB or could you use bluetooth HID as a keyboard? I've used the FLipMouse project to send keyboard commands to a PC/phone via GPIO contact closure on an ESP32 https://github.com/asterics/FLipMouse-esp32/

Answer (score 1):

USB devices never send anything on their own. To operate, they need a driver on host side to initiate transfers.

In most cases with odd bridges the USB devices are designated to "miscellaneous class" 0xEF, and need a device driver to start communications/device configurations. Usually MCHP supplies these drivers that need to be installed. Then these bridges use proprietary interface to get actual data in and out. 
That's why you need a library of various API calls on host side, and write an application that uses these calls to communicate with USB bridges as MCP22xx.

The MCP2210 bridge uses HID class as its basic interface, and thus it uses standard OS drivers, with no need of MCHP proprietary drivers.  That's apparently is their definition of "plug-n-play". However, conformance to HID class doesn't mean automatically that it is a keyboard, it can be mouse, or joystick, or barcode reader, so you still need their tools and libraries to configure the bridge and send/receive SPI data.

Comment: Wouldn't emulating a keyboard work as the USB keyboard drivers are usually there by default. No development work required on Win, Lin, Mac, etc.

Comment: I'm just curious why Microchip advertises it as Plug n' play if you always need a .dll incorporated within an application for it to function. Like - I literally just need it to type a few letters based on what the MCP2210 is getting from it's SPI bus.

Comment: OK, as commented under the original question, I know little about this. I thought this would be configurable in the MCP221x (whatever that is!).

Comment: @Transistor, actually there might be a difference, MCP 2210 does advertise in datasheet as "HID class", unlike MCP2221.

Comment: @Ali Chen Ah. I understand now. If I was going to make a background application for it that uses the API calls - how difficult would it be? Could I simply grab the info from the SPI bus using one of the RX API functions and then use a SendInput command to type out the string in the currently open program?

Comment: @FShiwani, MCHP provides full source code for MCP2210 "terminal program", visual BASIC style. Keep in mind that their libraries are 4-6 generations outdated, so you might need to try several "Visual Studios" to get it working.

Comment: @AliChen I just re-read your main post, you said I need their tools and libraries to configure the bridge. Is it possible to configure the MCP2210 as a HID keyboard using their tools and I can use it as a true plug n' play device on any other PC/Mac? Or is it necessary to always have an application program installed on a PC/Mac that interfaces with it.

Comment: @FShiwani I think you are confused by catchy "plug n play" term. Even if device really works as plug n play, it does not mean there is no software involved. What it means, in fact, is that OS will attempt to recognize device, _install_ required drivers and configure them for use with this particular device.

Comment: Ah. I see. So essentially, it will recognize it as a HID device and it allows access for the API to communicate with it. But in order to get any meaningful functionality out of it - I need to use the API.

Comment: Yes and no. If OS recognizes it as specific HID device, keyboard in your case, then you should be able to send key codes right away and they will be treated by _all_ applications as regular keyboard input. You wouldn't have to write any code. But if you want to do anything fancy, like insert codes into specific applications only, then you might be better with simpler bridge that creates COM port. Then your application can read whatever you send from COM port and do whatever you want with it

Comment: @Maple If it was somehow recognized as a keyboard - how exactly would I tell the MCP2210 from the ESP32 to press a key. Are there certain bytes to transmit(via SPI with ESP32) before a string to indicate that this is the string that should be typed as a HID keyboard?

Comment: If your device tells OS it is a keyboard it should behave as real keyboard, i.e. use same protocol other keyboards use and send scan codes, not letters. It is a task for _several layers_ of drivers in OS to transform scan codes into letters of currently selected language in currently active upper/lower case, locale etc.

Comment: @Transistor Your link gave me an idea. There's microcontrollers like the ATmega32U4 that have full USB support and can be configured to be a HID keyboard on the MCU itself. Couldn't I just use it's SPI/I2C interface to communicate with the ESP32?

Comment: I don't know but it seems reasonable.